# Get sesult from an ID and add to another ID in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want the value in variable a to be displayed in the div id "final-total"
Here is my index.php

```
<form action='index.php' method='POST'>
<table class='table table-bordered table-condensed'>
<tr>
<th class='text-center' width='12%'>Code</th>
<th class='text-center' width='12%'>Qty</th>
<th class='text-center' width='40%'>Item</th>
<th class='text-center' width='18%'>Rate</th>
<th class='text-center' width='18%'>Total</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type='text' name='code1' id='code1' size='4' class='text-center'>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='qty1' id='qty1' size='5' class='text-center'>
</td>
<td>
<div id='item1'></div>
</td>
<td>
<div id='rate1'></div>
</td>
<td>
<div id='total1'></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan='3' class='text-left'><b>Total:</b></td>
<td colspan='2'>
<b><div id='final-total'></div></b>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my js/global.js

```
$('input#code1').on('input', function(){
var name = $('input#code1').val();
if ($.trim(name) != ''){
$.post('ajax/item1.php', {code1: name}, function(data){
$('div#item1').text(data);
});
}
});
$('input#code1').on('input', function(){
var name = $('input#code1').val();
if ($.trim(name) != ''){
$.post('ajax/rate1.php', {code1: name}, function(data){
$('div#rate1').text(data);
});
}
});
$('input#qty1').on('input', function(){
var name = $('input#code1').val();
var qty = $('input#qty1').val();
if ($.trim(name) != ''){
$.post('ajax/ttl1.php', {code1: name, qty1: qty}, function(data){
$('div#total1').text(data);
});
}
});

var a = document.getElementById('div#ttl1').value;
document.getElementById("final-total").innerHTML = a;
```

Last two line in js/global.ls is not working

And here is what my item1.php looks like

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['code1']) === true && empty($_POST['code1']) === false) {
include('../db/connect.php');
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT `item_name` FROM `ftd_stock_v10.3` WHERE `code` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['code1']))."'");
echo (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? mysql_result($query, 0, 'item_name') :
```

'Item Not Found' ;
    }

And here is rate1.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['code1']) === true && empty($_POST['code1']) === false) {
include('../db/connect.php');
#checking for stock availability
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT `old_stock_bal` FROM `ftd_stock_v10.3` WHERE `code` = ?");
$stmt -> bind_param("s",$_POST['code1']);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($old_stock);
$stmt -> fetch();
$stmt -> close();
if($old_stock > 0){
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT `old_rate` FROM `ftd_stock_v10.3` WHERE `code` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['code1']))."'");
echo (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? mysql_result($query, 0, 'old_rate') : '0.000' ;
}else{
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT `new_rate` FROM `ftd_stock_v10.3` WHERE `code` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['code1']))."'");
echo (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? mysql_result($query, 0, 'new_rate') : '0.000' ;
}
}
```

And here is my ttl1.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['code1']) === true && empty($_POST['code1']) === false) {
include('../db/connect.php');
#checking for stock availability
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT `old_stock_bal` FROM `ftd_stock_v10.3` WHERE `code` = ?");
$stmt -> bind_param("s",$_POST['code1']);
$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> bind_result($old_stock);
$stmt -> fetch();
$stmt -> close();
if($old_stock > 0){
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT `old_rate` FROM `ftd_stock_v10.3` WHERE `code` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['code1']))."'");
echo (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? mysql_result($query, 0, 'old_rate') * 
$_POST['qty1'] : '0.000' ;
}else{
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT `new_rate` FROM `ftd_stock_v10.3` WHERE `code` = '".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['code1']))."'");
echo (mysql_num_rows($query) !== 0) ? mysql_result($query, 0, 'new_rate') * 
$_POST['qty1'] : '0.000' ;
}
}
```

I want the div with id "final-total" to get result of qty1 * rate1 and so on till qty10 * rate10, (all to summs added)

Note These are the files I have

```
index.php
js/global.js
db/connect.php

ajax/item1.php
.
.
ajax/item10.php

ajax/rate1.php
.
.
ajax/rate10.php

ajax/ttl1.php
.
.
ajax/ttl10.php
```

Comment: Does this even work? `document.getElementById('div#ttl1')`. Have you tried `console.log(a);` to see if there is a value?

Comment: Its not working, that what I am saying. Console shows nothinig

Answer (score 0):

if the element exist in DOM then mostly the issue is with this line

```
var a = document.getElementById('div#ttl1').value;
```

I presume it is

```js
var a = document.getElementById('ttl1').value;
document.getElementById("final-total").innerHTML = a;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ttl1" value="x">

<div id="final-total"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `getElementById()` like this, you need to use the [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function to find this item.

```js
var a = document.querySelector('div#ttl1').innerHTML;
document.getElementById("final-total").innerHTML = a;
```

```html
<div id="ttl1">Hello</div>

<div id="final-total"></div>
```

Or if you want to use the `getElementById()` function, you have to name only the id, like that: `getElementById('ttl1')`.

Comment: Tried, but not working! I got my div in `$.post('ajax/ttl1.php', {code1: name, qty1: qty}, function(data){
   $('div#total1').text(data);`

Tried your idea, but not helping me!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are doing. Can you please edit your question and provide more information.